# Railsアプリのパフォーマンス改善策でSQL発行回数を減らすには？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsアプリでのパフォーマンス改善対応を行っています。
よくあるパターンですが、ループ内にModelから取ったクラス変数があると
アクセスのたびにSQL発行してパフォーマンス劣化するということがありますが
これの改善策ってあったりしますでしょうか？
N+1ならincludesでeager loadするのが定石だと思いますが、
これとは別に対策するにはどのような方法がありますでしょうか？
どうかよろしくお願いします。

［追記］ソースを付記します
controller

```
  def ratings(args)
    @ratings = rating_response[:body]['items'].uniq { |rating| rating['work_id'] }.sort { |a, b| b['rating'] <=> a['rating'] }
    work_ids = @ratings.map { |rating| rating['work_id'] }
    @works = Work.where(resource_id: work_ids)
    render
  end
```

view

```
   tbody
      - @ratings.each do |rating|
        - work = @works.find_by(resource_id: rating["work_id"])
        - if work.blank?
          - next
        tr
          td
            = link_to work.resource_id, "https://#{somedomain}/#{work.resource_id}/", target: '_blank'
          td
```

特にModel同士でRelation組んだりとかして無く、@work.find_byがいけないのか

```
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x007f6e150166b8>>)> n
  Work Load (26.4ms)  SELECT  `works`.* FROM `works` WHERE `works`.`resource_id` IN (12652, 19584, 52842, 13079, 61785, 24657, 17732, 62705, 58215, 25900, 41473, 26710, 17522, 16348, 62092, 24517, 28466, 22101, 52609, 61766, 61219, 58327, 24796, 22172, 53589, 35546, 19453, 25870, 35378, 17434, 56209, 47797, 27907, 41119, 63235, 17524, 17523, 17515, 62706, 60183, 63448, 50583, 33323, 93564, 59342, 20553, 49100, 59704, 61684, 14470, 56308, 60890, 11649, 54247, 42777, 17609, 32642, 63302, 62415, 62309, 63078, 38673, 17525, 17521, 17519, 17517, 17516, 38057, 10905, 31822, 17527, 29125, 27717, 26746, 48703, 51970, 30309, 29680, 31142, 52149, 23952, 25197, 17109, 56878, 14035, 23756, 93082, 93052, 93053, 61057, 57613, 59634, 43869, 13433, 14526, 23403, 19164, 23624, 52856, 52060, 17425, 11240, 18880, 58425, 10349, 10373, 62534, 63307, 20408, 58943, 62864, 51122, 17424, 17436, 54246, 24997, 51535, 29782, 61265, 60674, 23782, 30903, 18067, 39484, 34789, 29829, 21785, 57837, 25784, 61068, 42482, 34673, 61003, 61059, 35486, 21203, 38659, 21787, 47059, 63044, 15095, 33392, 52875, 62759, 41627, 60398, 59114, 44762, 17520, 17518, 17514, 27147, 63500, 16577, 19234, 61097, 62607, 93572, 50630, 63480) AND `works`.`resource_id` = 19584 LIMIT 1
```

みたいな感じでselectが発行されます。なんでなんでしょう？最初に一回selectかけるだけで、あとはそこから都度取得というのが望ましいと考えています。可能でしょうか？

Comment: 都度sqlを発行するから時間がかかってるのであれば、loopに必要な情報をlocalに保持してからforすれば良いのでは？

Comment: Controllerから渡された変数に対して @somedata.each と直接しないで local = @somedataとした方がいいってことですか？

Comment: 具体的なコードを質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: わかりやすくするため、コード追記しました

Answer (score 1):

ビューを

```
@works.each do |work|
   ：
```

のループにすればいいのではないでしょうか。

今のコードはループの中で都度

```
Work.where(resource_id: work_ids).find_by(resource_id: ...)
```

を呼んでいるのと同じ意味になります。